# Smoothening my loss plot without boundary effects and without changing the list size

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, data-science

I have a python list of N elements, with losses from training a neural net. The losses are very noisy, so I'd like to smoothen the data. I've tried using [numpy.convolve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy.convolve), but it is problematic: there are three modes: 'full', 'same' and 'valid'. But 'full' and 'valid' have the problem that they produce a list that has a shorter length than the original, which is unhelpful, and 'same' has the problem that it under-estimates the loss at the start and end of the plot.

I'm using this function, which I got from [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/more-indicator-data-matplotlib-tutorial/):

```
def moving_average(values, window):
    weights = np.repeat(1.0, window) / window
    smas = np.convolve(values, weights, 'same')
    return list(smas)
```

and it produces this boundary effect:

[image]

Probably I'm just not doing it appropriately. Is there an appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps good to move the data to a dataframe and use functions such as `rolling` and `ewm`, which are commonly use for this cases or similar.

For Moving Averages:

```
short_rolling = data.rolling(window=20).mean()
```

or
Exponential Moving Average (EMA):

```
ema_short = data.ewm(span=20, adjust=False).mean()
```

From: https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-finance-part-3-moving-average-trading-strategy/